# Update a value in a tree

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming, elm

I have some state that is represented as a tree

```
type Tree state 
  = Branch (List (Tree state))
  | Leaf state
```

and I have a function to update the individual leaves given some action

```
updateLeaf : action -> state -> state
```

I would like a way to represent actions in some structure

```
type Structure action = ...
```

which carries an action and some means to know precisely which leaf in the tree to update.

For example, suppose I have the following tree:

```
Branch 
  [ Leaf "foo"
  , Leaf "bar"
  , Branch 
      [ Leaf "baz"
      , Branch []
      , Leaf "qux"
      ]
  ]
```

and I get some action say, "hello" and I would like it to apply my updateLeaf function **only** on "baz" in such a way that I end up with

```
Branch 
  [ Leaf "foo"
  , Leaf "bar"
  , Branch 
      [ Leaf "bazhello"
      , Branch []
      , Leaf "qux"
      ]
  ]
```

assuming my updateLeaf function is just string concatenation or `(++)`. Furthermore, I would need this to pretty generic as in the structure would somehow track the position in the tree of the leaf it wishes to update.

In essence what I am looking for is for the following function:

```
updateTree 
  : (action -> state -> state)
 -> Structure action
 -> Tree state
 -> Tree state
```

which will figure out which leaf in the tree to apply the given update function.

Finally, I also need it to work with address forwarding. Suppose the each leaf of the tree is represented as a button

```
viewLeaf : Address action -> state -> Html
viewLeaf address state = 
  button 
    [ onClick address ... ]
    [ ... ]
```

and further suppose that the actions sent by the button on click are the ones that will update the state.

I would like to be able to define the following function

```
viewTree 
  : (Address action -> state -> Html)
 -> Address (Structure action) 
 -> Tree state
 -> Html
```

such that I can view all those buttons and the addresses are forwarded accordingly such that each button only affects itself. (I'm only interested in the forwarding aspect, not the visuals).

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Is this `Structure a` value supposed to identify exactly one leaf in the tree?  
And I assume that the `Structure` identifies a leaf to perform the update on by its position in the tree and not by its current value?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Something analogous to an array index if you will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that zippers allow one to achieve this. I will walkthrough the solution.

Using the following zipper

```
type alias Crumb a = 
  { left  : List (Tree a)
  , right : List (Tree a)
  }

type alias Zipper a = (Tree a, List (Crumb a))
```

One merely needs to implement the following functions

```
zipperMap : (Zipper a -> a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b 
zipperUpdate : Zipper a -> (a -> a) -> Tree a -> Tree a
```

These can be implemented as follows

```
zipperMap : (Zipper a -> a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b 
zipperMap f tree = 
  let 
      applyZipper ((subtree, crumbs) as zipper) = 
        case subtree of 
          Leaf a ->
            Leaf (f zipper a)

          Branch subtrees ->
            subtrees 
            |> List.indexedMap (\index _ -> gotoIndex index zipper |> Maybe.map applyZipper)
            |> keepJusts
            |> Branch

  in 
      applyZipper (fromTree tree)



zipperUpdate : Zipper a -> (a -> a) -> Tree a -> Tree a
zipperUpdate zipper f tree = 
  zipperMap (\z a -> if z == zipper then f a else a) tree
```

Where `keepJusts` is filters out the nothings from a list of maybes

```
keepJusts : List (Maybe a) -> List a
```

and `gotoIndex` goes to the nth subtree in a zipper

```
gotoIndex : Int -> Zipper a -> Maybe (Zipper a)
gotoIndex index (tree, bs) = 
  case tree of
    Leaf _ ->
      Nothing

    Branch subtrees ->
      case nth index subtrees of 
        Nothing ->
          Nothing 

        Just newTree ->
          let 
              newCrumb = 
                { left  = List.take index subtrees
                , right = List.drop (index + 1) subtrees
                }
          in 
              Just (newTree, newCrumb :: bs)
```

Now, given the functions `zipperMap` and `zipperUpdate` we can apply these on our state.

Let us assume that the actions on the trees are represented as follows

```
type Action action state
  = ChildAction (Zipper state) action
```

We can implement our `update` function as follows

```
update : (action -> state -> state)
      -> Action action state
      -> Tree state 
      -> Tree state
update updateChild action state = 
  case action of 
    ChildAction zipper childAction -> 
      zipperUpdate zipper (updateChild childAction) state
```

And we can implement our `view` function as follows

```
view : (Address action -> state -> Html) 
    -> Address (Action action state) 
    -> Tree state 
    -> Html
view viewChild address state = 
  let 
      viewZ zipper child = 
        let 
            childAddress = 
              Signal.forwardTo address (ChildAction zipper)

        in 
            viewChild childAddress child

  in 
      state
      |> zipperMap viewZ
      |> toList
      |> div []
```

Where `toList` converts a tree to a list. While this is just an example, it helps illustrate how one can work with such things.

For more detail, you can see a fully functioning example [here](https://gist.github.com/TheSeamau5/dee7da3b1646f24cf06f)

Answer (score 3):

A [zipper](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers) is a way to navigate and modify a data structure. Suppose you have a tree, and you walk down the tree by choosing a branch. After 3 steps you encounter a leaf and you with to modify it. Now you want to return the modified tree, but you're 3 levels deep, how do you step back? Suppose that every time you go down a level in a tree, you leave a trail of breadcrumbs, so that you can reverse a step and reconstruct the tree. In other words, instead of just a tree you have a tuple (tree, breadcrumbs).

```
type Tree state = Branch (List (Tree state)) | Leaf state
-- Crumb contains 2 lists:
-- leafs/branches to the left of your focus
-- leafs/branches to the right of your focus
type Crumb state = Crumb (List (Tree state)) (List (Tree state))
type alias Zipper state = (Tree state, List (Crumb state))

tree : Tree String
tree = Branch [Leaf "foo",Leaf "bar",Branch [Leaf "baz",Branch [],Leaf "qux"]]
```

Every time you choose a branch, you cons the parent node and all other branches you didn't choose into breadcrumbs. Then you choose a new branch, so you cons its parent mode and all new branches you didn't choose in breadcrumbs. Therefore breadcrumbs contain all relevant information to reconstruct the previous step in reverse order. Let's implement going up and going to a leaf by name in a tree:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)

break : (a -> Bool) -> List a -> (List a, List a)
break p xs = case (List.head xs, List.tail xs) of
  (Nothing, Nothing) -> ([], [])
  (Just x, Just xs') -> if p x
                        then ([], xs)
                        else let (ys,zs) = break p xs'
                             in (x::ys,zs)

treeInit : Tree state -> Zipper state
treeInit t = (t, [])

treeUp : Zipper state -> Zipper state
treeUp (subtree, Crumb l r::bs) = (Branch <| l++[subtree]++r, bs)

treeTo : state -> Zipper state -> Zipper state
treeTo name (Branch subtrees, bs) =
  let (l, x::r) = break (\(Leaf name') -> name == name') subtrees
  in (x, Crumb l r::bs)

main = tree |> treeInit |> treeTo "foo" |> show
```

But this doesn't allow to move focus from root to `Leaf "baz"` and doesn't allow to modify it, so let's add more functions (note that all our zipper functions can crash, we'll change this soon):

```
(!!) : List a -> Int -> a
xs !! i = case List.tail xs of
  Nothing -> Debug.crash "index out of bounds"
  Just xs' -> if i == 0
              then case List.head xs of Just x -> x
              else xs' !! (i-1)

treeToIndex : Int -> Zipper state -> Zipper state
treeToIndex i (Branch subtrees, bs) =
  (subtrees!!i, Crumb (List.take i subtrees) (List.drop (i+1) subtrees)::bs)

treeReplace : state -> Zipper state -> Zipper state
treeReplace new (Leaf old, bs) = (Leaf new, bs)

main = tree |> treeInit |> treeToIndex 2 |> treeTo "baz" |> treeReplace "xyzzy" |> show
```

This whole chain of functions can crash easily if there is an index bigger than the branch size, or you try to go up from the root, and so on. Instead we should wrap the results in `Maybe`, so that instead of a crash, `Nothing` is returned. But how do we chain functions, now that they return `Maybe (Zipper state)`, while they still accept `Zipper state`? This is where you use [`andThen`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Maybe#andThen), which has the type `Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b`. Full code of your zipper below:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)
import Maybe exposing (andThen)

type Tree state = Branch (List (Tree state)) | Leaf state
-- Crumb contains 2 lists:
-- leafs/branches to the left of your focus
-- leafs/branches to the right of your focus
type Crumb state = Crumb (List (Tree state)) (List (Tree state))
type alias Zipper state = (Tree state, List (Crumb state))

tree : Tree String
tree = Branch [Leaf "foo",Leaf "bar",Branch [Leaf "baz",Branch [],Leaf "qux"]]

break : (a -> Bool) -> List a -> (List a, List a)
break p xs = case (List.head xs, List.tail xs) of
  (Nothing, Nothing) -> ([], [])
  (Just x, Just xs') -> if p x
                        then ([], xs)
                        else let (ys,zs) = break p xs'
                             in (x::ys,zs)

treeInit : Tree state -> Zipper state
treeInit t = (t, [])

treeUp : Zipper state -> Maybe (Zipper state)
treeUp (subtree, bs) = case bs of
  [] -> Nothing
  Crumb l r::bs' -> Just (Branch <| l++[subtree]++r, bs')

treeTo : state -> Zipper state -> Maybe (Zipper state)
treeTo name node = case node of
  (Branch subtrees, bs) ->
    let (l, x::r) = break (\(Leaf name') -> name == name') subtrees
    in Just (x, Crumb l r::bs)
  _ -> Nothing

(!!) : List a -> Int -> Maybe a
xs !! i = case List.tail xs of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just xs' -> if i == 0
              then List.head xs
              else xs' !! (i-1)

treeToIndex : Int -> Zipper state -> Maybe (Zipper state)
treeToIndex i (Branch subtrees, bs) =
  let newTree = subtrees!!i
  in case newTree of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just newTree ->
      let newCrumb = Crumb (List.take i subtrees) (List.drop (i+1) subtrees)
      in Just (newTree, newCrumb::bs)

treeReplace : state -> Zipper state -> Maybe (Zipper state)
treeReplace new node = case node of
  (Leaf old, bs) -> Just (Leaf new, bs)
  _ -> Nothing

-- the function you're interested in most likely
treeUpdate : (state -> state) -> Zipper state -> Maybe (Zipper state)
treeUpdate f node = case node of
  (Leaf name, bs) -> Just (Leaf (f name), bs)
  _ -> Nothing

main = (tree |> treeInit |> treeToIndex 2)
       `andThen` treeTo "baz" `andThen` treeReplace "xyzzy"
       `andThen` treeUp `andThen` treeUp |> show
```

*(Feel absolutely free to ask questions and clarifications, and I will update and improve this answer)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I'm starting to understand this whole zipper thing but it still feels a little cryptic as to how I get the addresses to work.

In essence, I'm still stuck in what I am trying to do. I've written up a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/TheSeamau5/59c2570fda4dbc412ff7), hopefully it makes the question a bit clearer. Thanks again for your help. https://gist.github.com/TheSeamau5/59c2570fda4dbc412ff7

Comment: Thanks to your answer I've finally cracked it. It really put me on the right track. I shall update my question to feature the answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a [zipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)).  Does everything you ask for in terms of

1. specifying a unique location in the tree
2. allowing modifications to the focus while preserving the rest.
3. easy reassembly of the tree.

If you want to bundle modifications with the precise location, then you just have to build a type which includes the zipper and the action.

There's a good section on zippers in [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers).

Once you understand the concept, it's easily applicable to many other datastructures.

Comment: How would you use a zipper in the context described above? By this i mean, what would it look like, what would the update function look like, and how would address forwarding look like?